# How to append a variable at the end of one field while Joining two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a field in my database table with the name of commment_user. In this field I have stored the comment_id + user_id in the following format

```
110-26
```

in the above line 110 is the comment_id and 26 is the user_id. Now I want to LEFT JOIN the two tables.

I have a left Join

```
`comments LEFT JOIN votes on comments.commment_user = votes.comment_id`
```

But I want to append the user_id at the end of votes.comment_id 
for example

```
`comments LEFT JOIN votes on comments.commment_user(13-10) = (votes.comment_id(13) - user_id(10))`
```

This is not the correct SQL query, because I don't know how to do that in sql, it is just to make you understand.

In the above example `(votes.comment_id(13) - user_id(10))` it does not show '-' as minus but it means 13-10.
So, Is it possible to append user_id at the end of one field while Joining two tables, If yes, How can I write it in sql query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want the `concat()` function:

```
comments LEFT JOIN
votes
on comments.commment_user = concat(votes.comment_id, '-', votes.user_id)
```

Although this solves your problem, I would recommend storing `comment_id` and `user_id` separately in the `votes` table.  Fiddling with such a combination makes the database less efficient.  In this case, the problem is magnified because the engine has to compare ids (which are presumably numeric) to strings.